# How to execute a splash fragment only once?

Tags: android, android-fragments, splash-screen

I'm developing an app with several activities made up by several fragments as well. In the `MainActivity` there is a `SplashFragment`: I want it to be executed **only** at the start of the app, but whenever I go back to the `MainActivity` using the back button displayed in the action bar of another activity it starts `SplashFragment` as well. Note that using the hardware back button on the smartphone works: `SplashFragment` won't be executed. I tried to save a boolean in a bundle (inside `MainActivity.java`). It should keep track of the displayed splash screen, but it still behaves as I said before.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("splashed", true);
}
```

Comment: Its unclear how you manage your fragments, perhaps you can add some code

Comment: It seems like what you want here is actually not related to Android. Just keep an application wide variable that indicates if the Splash screen has been shown or not and only display when the variable is false.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);` on `Splash` class?

Comment: I'm talking about a splash **fragment**, not an activity.

Comment: Maybe it will work using `finish();` on `MainActivity` them, when press the back buttom. Like This: `@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    //replaces the default 'Back' button action
    if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start the activity manually, i.e by calling startActivity() you could put an extra in the intent that says you are already in the app so the splash fragment does not need to be shown:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class;
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `MainActivity` put:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("EXTRA")){
    if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean("EXTRA")){
        //dont show splash
    } else {
        //show splash
    }
} else {
    //show splash
}
```